# How to replace single quote in Java with Postgres?

Tags: java, postgresql

How to replace single quote in Java with Postgres?

```
select * from where id in ('<45646300.KDSFJJSKJSDF95'fdgdfgdfgd>', 'fdgdfgdg');
```

I always use params like

```
select * from where id = ?;
```

But in this case i have problem, where i have 'in' statement with string passed to it.

I wish to replace all dangerous chars

Comment: Better to provide a table name. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to continue using `PreparedStatement`s rather than to escape characters manually.

In the case of `IN` clause you can generate a query with appropriate number of `?`s dynamically.

```
String[] input = ...;

StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
b.append("select * from where id in (");
b.append("?"); // Assume that input contains at least one element
for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) b.append(", ?");
b.append(")");

PreparedStatement s = c.prepareStatement(b.toString());

for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) s.setString(i + 1, input[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache commons API provides multiples ways to remove dangerous chars for specific languages such as CSS, Javascript SQL, etc...

Take a look at this if it helps : http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard SQL quoting for single quotes:

```
select * 
from the_table
where id in ('<45646300.KDSFJJSKJSDF95''fdgdfgdfgd>', 'fdgdfgdg');
```

So any embedded single quote needs to be written twice.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
select * from TABLE_NAME where id in (?);
```

Comment: Yes. But i have array or string delimited by ','. String param = "'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'". I dont know how to pass it

Comment: like this: prepStat.setString(1, myString);

Answer (score 0):

There's a page explaining the different options [over here on the javaranch site](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200510/Journal200510.jsp#a2)